# Modal Dialog with Multiple Forms

Tags: vb.net, forms, modal-dialog

Is there a way to specify what forms are Locked when opening a Modal Dialog?

I want to have a specific form available even if a Modal dialog is opened.

The form in question is a child form (Accessible from the Windows application bar), that is created from the main application form.  The Modal Dialog should only lock the main application form, and not the secondary window.

Anyone know how to do this?

EDIT:
I guess this is not very easy to do.  Anyone know if it is possible to make a secondary form independant from the main application form?  Would you need to create a seperate solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using the ShowDialog() method, the answer is probably not.  But if you were to create a shared collection of forms, you could could attempt to replicate it using a combination of Locked and TopMost properties.

But, it may be more trouble that it is worth to fight against the windows standards that are expected by most users.